# Algoritimo Ford-Fulkerson Python

Tags: python, grafo

estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade onde preciso implementar o algoritmo de  Ford-Fulkerson em Python. Porém estou tendo dificuldade em achar um caminho aumentante no grafo residual (função caminho). Não sei se é a recursão que não está funcionando, ou o for. Ainda sou iniciante em python, contudo pode ser problema na lógica.

```
graph={}
graphIni={}
caminho=[]
graphresidual={}
s = 0
t = 2
def criaGrafo():
    lista = input().split(' ')
    nVertice = int(lista[0])
    nAresta = int(lista[1])
    s = int(lista[2])
    t = int(lista[3])



    graph[s]= {}
    for x in range(0,nVertice):
        if(x!=t and x!=s):
            auxl={}
            graph[x]=auxl
    graph[t]= {}

    for x in range(0,nAresta):
        lista=input().split(" ")
        v1 = int(lista[0])
        v2 = int(lista[1])
        capMax = int(lista[2])
        graph[v1].update({v2:capMax})

    graphIni[s]= {}
    for x in range(0,nVertice):
        if(x!=t and x!=s):
            auxl={}
            graphIni[x]=auxl
    graphIni[t]= {}
    for x in graph:
        for y in graph[x]:
            graphIni[x].update({y:0})

def minimo(u, v):
    if(u < v):
        return u
    else:
        return v

def Graforesidual(graph, graphIni):
    for x in graph:
        aux = {}
        graphresidual[x] = aux
    for x in graph:
        for y in graph[x]:
            graphresidual[x].update({y:(graph[x][y] - graphIni[x][y])})
            if(graphIni[x][y] != 0):
                graphresidual[y].update({x:graphIni[x][y]})
    return graphresidual
def Caminho(graphresidual, u, t, caminho):
    if(u == t):
        return caminho
    else:
        for x in graphresidual[u]:
            caminho.append(x)
            Caminho(graphresidual, x, t, caminho)
            if caminho[-1::] == t:
                return caminho
        if(caminho[-1::] != t):
            print("nao tem caminho")
criaGrafo()
Graforesidual(graph, graphIni)
graphresidual = Graforesidual(graph, graphIni)
print(graphresidual)
print(Caminho(graphresidual, s, t, caminho))
```

um exemplo de entrada seria:

```
6 9 0 5
0 1 15
0 3 20
1 2 10
1 4 5
2 4 15
2 5 10
3 1 5
3 4 8
4 5 20
```

Comment: Para esse exemplo de entrada, qual seria a saída?

Comment: Acredito que para essa entrada o fluxo máximo é 23. Só que o algoritmo está faltando bastante coisa até calcular o fluxo. Por enquanto o que a função Caminho deveria retornar é algum dos possíveis caminhos aumentantes do primeiro grafo residual, como por exemplo {0, 3, 4, 5} ou {0,1,2,5} ou {0,1,3,4,5} ou {0, 1, 4, 5}, entre outros possíveis

Comment: Explica um pouco melhor a função Caminho. O que são 'u' e 't'? Por que retornar 'caminho' se são iguais? O que são as entradas e o que é a saída?